# How to make a python 3 file executable and pause after running

Tags: raspbian, python, file

I want to make a file executable, but I don't know how to do that and have the idle prompt appear afterward.  Is the best way to just open idle and then import the file?  I'm using python3 on raspbian jessie.  Can you add flags like -i when you make the file executable?  Please help.

**Update**  I found that adding the -i flag in the beginning of the file works.

Comment: What does pause the script mean? If you write an executable you tend to keep the script running and you can close or kill it. And yes you are add flags when making files executable

Comment: Pause meaning not exiting after running; stopping and showing the python prompt.  And I mean a flag like when you run a python file with python: `python3 -i blahblah.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Keep all your executable files in a folder, I usually keep it in `/home/pi/`. Your folder can be called for example `exec`

   ```
   mkdir exec
   ```
2. move your Python3 script into this folder:

   ```
   mv myScript.py ~/exec/
   ```
3. In your `myScript.py` add the *shebang line* on the top-most part of script

   ```
   $ nano myScript.py

   ## add this line on top of file
   !/usr/bin/python3
   ```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and in the end <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

5. give executable rights to your file:

   $ chmod +x myScript.py

**Additional** : you can also remove the `.py` from the file and keep it just `myScript`

```
    mv myScript.py myScript
```

You have your script as an executable you can trigger it by doing a simple

```
   ./myScript
```

#### Pausing Scripts

I think this is inherent to the script you have written, you can use `time.sleep` in your script to pause the working and do something in the meantime for e.g. print something or do nothing.

### Adding Arguments

You can use `configParser` module in Python to give arguments to your script

Your executable will now run as:

```
./myScript -arg1 -arg2
```

#### Links

[Python3 ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/configparser.html)

[time.sleep() for Pausing Python scripts](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/)

**Edit**:

[Parse Flags to a Python Executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815187/how-to-parse-flags-to-a-python-executable)

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew how to make it executable.  I was trying to make running `./file.py` the same as running `python3 *-i* file.py`

Answer (score 0):

I am running python 3.7.3 on a Raspberry Pi 3. I found that I needed to change the line at the top of the file from

```
!/usr/bin/python3
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

in order to get it to work.